# How to change link url from format html?

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$str = '<html><p><img src="http://test.com/images.jpg" /><img src="test.com/image2.jpg"><p><html>';
$str_rep = str_replace('/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i','http://mywebsite.com/', $str);
```

I want to replace the image URL using a regular expression. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you meant **str** _replace?

Comment: @zerkms: you can using other function()(not use str_replace()), how to ideas?

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to replace the image URL with a *regular expression*, you want to [parse the HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-way-to-parse-html-with-php) and then manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace($regex, $replace_with, $string)` to match and replace using regular expressions.

```
preg_replace('/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i', 'http://mywebsite.com/', $str);
```

[preg_replace in PHP manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)